# Using Boolean operators in FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving, boolean-computation

The section on Boolean operators suggests that `FindInstance` can be applied to them. However, when I try to use it I get a rather confusing error:

```
Horses :=
  (Result == 100 / Speed) &&
  ((Horse == 1) \[Equivalent] (Speed == 1)) &&
  ((Horse == 2) \[Equivalent] (Speed == 20))

Result = 5
FindInstance[Horses, {Horse}]
```

produces the dreaded *not a quantified system of equations and inequalities* error with no statement of which part is the problem.

Can I not use the relational operator `Equivalent` in `FindInstance`, or is what I'm trying to do generally invalid?

Comment: The documentation of FindInstance suggests to me that it can solve satisfiability problems on Boolean statements which contain Boolean-valued variables (I.e. with a True/False value). Your case is trying to solve an algebraic equation with real-valued variables, expressed as a logical statement. I saw no indication that this is possible with FindInstance.

Comment: I saw a comment that <=> isn’t a valid operator. What I actually entered was ESC <=> ESC which I’m not sure how to represent on SO. I’m surprised if using the function call form alone fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your corrected code works well:

```
Horses := (Result == 100/Speed) &&Equivalent[(Horse == 1), (Speed == 1)] && 
Equivalent[(Horse == 2), (Speed == 20)];Result = 5;
FindInstance[Horses, {Horse, Speed}]
```

> {{Horse -> 2, Speed -> 20}}

Comment: Great. I did have a really bizarre follow-up, though. I then tried change Horse==1 to Horse=="Nag", and Horse==2 to Horse=="Thoroughbred". This caused Mathematica to give a bizarre error message that "the system contains a nonconstant expression Nag", even though Nag should just be a string literal. Even changing it to String["Nag"] didn't stop this error. Weird.

Comment: ... Also, adding `&& MemberQ[{1,2},Horse]` to the `Horses` system makes it return no instances, even though the instance above makes that true also.